# d2: not getting any backtrace info

Tags: linux, d, backtrace

I'm playing with the gtkd wrapper generator, and running into an std.conv exception for which I cannot manage to get any symbolic debug info at all. I've compiled with debug symbols:

```
$ dmd -gc -debug utils/HTODConvert.d utils/WrapperIF.d utils/funct.d utils/DefReader.d utils/GtkWrapper.d utils/HtmlStrip.d utils/IndentedStringBuilder.d utils/convparms.d utils/GtkDClass.d -ofgtkwrap
```

but the backtrace is just a list of memory addresses:

```
std.conv.ConvException@/usr/include/d/std/conv.d(1779): Unexpected ' ' when converting from type string to type int
----------------
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x805c4ab]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x805c57a]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x806d49e]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x806924e]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8068c4a]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8066aed]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8066824]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x806388f]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x806367c]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x805e988]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x805e910]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x805e793]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x805d6f5]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8060176]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8071140]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8070c50]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8071182]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8070c50]
/home/martin/code/d/GtkD/wrap/gtkwrap() [0x8070c04]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0xb7dce3d5]
```

This is under 32-bit linux

```
$ uname -a
Linux mercury 3.3.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 14 10:08:43 UTC 2012 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8600 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

$ dmd -v
DMD32 D Compiler v2.059
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that your dmd.conf has `-L--export-dynamic` in its `DFLAGS`. I believe that the version provided with dmd has it, but without that, you won't get the function names, so there's a good chance that it's missing from your dmd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Start your program with GDB and you'll get a proper stacktrace, unfortunatly I don't know of any other way (You need to compile with -g and -gc).